# Ubuntu 22.04 Screen Stays Blank after Wake up from Hibernate

Tags: boot, grub2, hibernate

**Issue:**

- Computer does not wake up after clicking suspend in the power menu. I just have a permanent black screen.

**System:**

- Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-4690K
- Graphics: AMD R9 280X
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

**Extra Info**

- I used to not be able to reboot either, but I made the following adjustment in my grub settings.
- Original: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
- By adding the 'reboot=pci' to this, my computer now does not freeze with a black screen on reboot.

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force reboot=pci"

My main question is whether there is an analogous option for the hibernation settings?

Cheers,
Brian

Comment: how did you try to wake the computer? did you press the power button?

Comment: Yes, I pressed the power button. Originally it is blinking, but it switches to solid on with the fans running. The computer does not respond to keyboard or mouse input at this state.